# How to traverse a dataset with bash shell

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm running code in a computer vision deep learning project, and I can run demo successfully.
Now I want to use demo to create a new big dataset. The command to run one picture is:

```
cd /root/.virtualenvs/hmr2.0/hmr2.0-master/src/visualise/
python3 demo.py --image=im00001.jpg --model=base_model --setting=paired-joints --joint_type=cocoplus --init_toes=false
```

And there is a dataset in

```
cd /root/.virtualenvs/hmr2.0/hmr2.0-master/src/visualise/images, including 10000 pictures. They are named im00001.jpg, im00002.jpg to im09999.jpg, im10000.jpg.
```

How can I write a bash shell to run all the 10000 images and generate out files with corresponding names?

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks I usually do something like

```
cd /root/.virtualenvs/hmr2.0/hmr2.0-master/src/visualise
for fff in images/*.jpg; do
    python3 demo.py --image=$fff --model=base_model --setting=paired-joints --joint_type=cocoplus --init_toes=false
done
```

If there are other jpg files in that directory, you'll have to replace the "images/*.jpg" by something more specific

If the `for fff in images/*.jpg` doesn't work due to the large number of images, you can replace that with

```
ls -1 images/*.jpg | while read fff; do
```

Comment: [Never parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Use `find images -name '*.jpg'` instead.

Comment: I agree with the StackExchange opinion, but there's always the trade of between getting done something fast and getting it done bullet-proof. My solution here is a fast one, but most certainly not bullet proof. Hence it's perfect for a one-time action. Using find instead improves it somewhat, but then I'd use the `-print0` action; blanks can cause nasty side effects. Instead, trying to `find images  -name im[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg`  (works in `ls` as well) would also reduce many potential problems. If it is a tool, make it rock solid. If it's a one-time task, optimize for speed.